# Правильный способ скрытия клавиатуры при клике, свайпе по области не входящий в EditText

Tags: android

Правило должно работать только внутри определенного фрагмента (Fragment).

Видел пару разных примеров. Но хотел бы использовать более правильный и компактный вариант. Есть ли он?

В цикле устанавливать всем вьюшкам touch listener и закрывать при таче - ну как то кажется что костыль)